# sql/access_order by sum of rows_select top

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have searched for an answer here, but have not found yet. I have a table
It has 8 columns.

```
Company_code - integer
Company name - text
Product code - integer
Product description - text
Cost of every transaction - double 
Weight - double
Country of origin - text
```

Here is a link to an access document http://we.tl/3yjzrXW5Bc
Every row is an import transaction every company did. There are many rows for every company code. I need to choose top 20 companies by sum of **cost of every transaction**. I need to ORDER companies by their SUM (cost).

I tried many queries but none worked. I ended up with this

```
SELECT *
  FROM groupping
 ORDER BY sum([cost]) DESC;
```

I am learning sql ad It would be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: share your table schema and dummy data

Comment: I attached a link to a picture of the table. the headers are in English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 queries :

- one to do the sum by company (as shown by Mureinik with the code instead of the name of the company)
- one to get your result, with all your columns
  both are linked with the company_code (I presume this is the primary key)

But beware : ONE query is made to answer ONE question. Having the weight in the same row than the sum of the cost will probably give a unwanted result.
Try to represent want you want with a small (but representative) set of data in Excel to fix up your idea.

Comment: Tank you Mureinik and ypicot your quiries worked and I have achieved my goal!=)

Answer (score 1):

You can query the sum (with grouping), order by it, and apply `top`:

```
SELECT   TOP 20 company_name, SUM(cost)
FROM     groupping
GROUP BY company_name
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: thank you for your post. Yes, I know it will work. But I need to have all the columns. I need something like SELECT  TOP 20 [comp_code], [comp_name], [comp_address], [comp_code], [weight], [cost], [country] FROM groupping  ORDER BY sum(cost) DESC. I need to order companies by sum of cost (sum of several rows in a cost column) and keep the rest of the columns in a new table. I think maybe i need to create two tables. I do not know which yet.